# I can't set cookies on Tornado/Python

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I am with a problem that I am not understanding the reason... Basically I can't set cookies on Tornado/Python, either normal cookie or secure cookie. My code:

```
class API(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):

        self.set_secure_cookie("a_cookie", "a_value")
        a_cookie = self.get_secure_cookie("a_cookie")

        print(">>> a_cookie ", a_cookie)

        self.set_cookie("a_cookie", "a_value")
        a_cookie = self.get_cookie("a_cookie")

        print(">>> a_cookie ", a_cookie)
```

The output is:

```
>>> a_cookie  None
>>> a_cookie  None
```

The class BaseHandler extends the tornado.web.RequestHandler.

About the secure cookie, I set the cookie_secret.

I am not understanding the reason of when I set a cookie, I can't get it. I believe that I'm following the rules on sites (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/security.html , https://technobeans.com/2012/08/07/tornado-cookies/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is that - **cookies are set on the next request, not on the current**.

`get_cookie` gets the cookies which are already present in the incoming request, i.e. the cookies sent by the browser.

---

This is how cookies work:

1. Browser sends a request to a server
2. Server sends an HTTP response to the browser with a cookie
3. The browser will then save the cookie.
4. In every request after that, browser will send that cookie back to the server.

After that, `get_cookie` will be able to get the cookie from the incoming request.

---

If you run `API` handler second time, you will see the value of the cookie in the output.

See the [source code for `get_cookie`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L520-L531) on github for more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Now I understand what really happens. :D